# error in App.js "export 'firebaseConfig' was not found in './config'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Used version 8.2.3 and 8.2.10 of firebase. Still same error. expo version is 43. Error is coming on running expo start in cmd

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAh_tcl1uBG72zmb3q-vOO6U7o6U4M6ueQ",
  authDomain: XXX,
  projectId: XXX,
  storageBucket: XXX,
  messagingSenderId: XXX,
  appId: XXX
};
```

```
if(!firebase.apps.length){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default firebase.database();
```

Comment: Can you share the file where config is being imported?

Comment: https://github.com/MahimaAsthana/Spectagram